# Finding Digits in a String

Tags: python, string, loops, printing

I'm very new to python and am having trouble with the following bit of code. The aim is to create a function that prints all the integers within a string.

```
def get_digits(str1):
   for i in str1:
      if i.isdigit():
        return i
```

However it is only returning the first integer in the string, and I am unsure on how to get it to print all of them.

My apologies if the question is stupid, I have looked around for a while on this site and others and haven't been able to work it out.

Answer (score 3):

Condensed down into a list comprehension

```
def get_digits(strval):
    return [i for i in strval if i.isdigit()]

print get_digits('432jfsd5fs')
print ''.join(get_digits('432jfsd5fs'))
```

Returns

```
['4', '3', '2', '5']
4325
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> def print_digits(str1):
...    for i in str1:
...       if i.isdigit():
...           print i
... 
>>> print_digits("a12b3")
1
2
3
```

`print` prints things.  `return` sends the answer back to whatever ran the function.  i guess you are confusing the two because if you run a function within python it prints whatever is returned.  but that is only because python is trying to be helpful and show you the result; it's not how you normally print things.

if you really want return the digits, and print them elsewhere, then one way to do it is build a list of results:

```
>>> def get_digits(str1):
...    results = []
...    for i in str1:
...       if i.isdigit():
...          results.append(i)
...    return results
... 
>>> print(get_digits("a12b3"))
['1', '2', '3']
```

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you return from a function, the function stops executing.  I would recommend a [generator](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) here, which allows you to return an iterable from a function without writing much code.

This question smacks of homework, so I'm not going to give the full answer, but I would recommend looking at [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/231855/960195) for a great explanation of generators and the `yield` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the digits and return a list of them, like this:

```
def get_digits(str1):
   digits = [] # define new list
   for i in str1:
      if i.isdigit():
        digitis.append(i) # i is a digit, append to list
   return digits # return the list of digits
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function quits after it finds the first digit. In order for it to return all the digits, collect the results in a list.

```
def get_digits(str1):
   digits = []
   for i in str1:
      if i.isdigit():
        digits.append(i)
   return digits
```

You can also simplify your function, by using a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
def get_digits(str1):
   return [d for d in str1 if d.isdigit()]
```

If you just want to print the results and not return them, replace `return i` with `print i` in your original function.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
re.findall('\d', str1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_digits(str1):
   numbers = ""
   for i in str1:
      if i.isdigit():
        numbers = numbers + i
   return numbers
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple explanation:

```
# your code
def get_digits(str1):
   for i in str1:
      if i.isdigit():
        return i
```

when a function meets `return i`, it stops its further execution, and return the value.

---

Since others has explained in detail, I'll just put more solutions for reference:

```
#1. Using generator
def get_digits_generator(str1):
    for i in str1:
       if i.isdigit():
           yield i
```

---

```
#2. Returning a list of digits
def get_digits_list(str1):
    list_of_digits = []
    for i in str1:
       if i.isdigit():
           list_of_digits.append(i)
    return list_of_digits
```

---

```
#3. List comprehension
str1 = "asdbh12njasdo29ns"
list_of_digits = [character for character in str1 if character.isdigit()]
```

Answer (score -3):

```
a=""
def get_digits(str1):
   for i in str1:
      if i.isdigit():
        a=a&i
   return a
```

try it like this. Because you return while you find the first digital.

Comment: This isn't valid Python (the `&` operator can't be used on strings) and the formatting is… suboptimal.